# How to check if site is online with JavaScript? Plus tips on how to make the rest of this function work better

Tags: javascript, function

I need to check if a website is online and to get ping time.

I already have a rough ping time (close enough). But I still need to check if the site is online and make the function run five times, and get the lowest ping value (in order to get it more accurate).

My code so far:

```
<script>
  function initPingTest(siteUrl){
    pingTester();
    function pingTester(){
      document.getElementById('site').innerHTML = '<center>' + siteUrl + '</center>';
      document.getElementById('pingT').innerHTML = '<center> testing.. </center>';
    var startTime=new Date();
    window.startTime=startTime.getTime();
    var imgSrc=siteUrl+ '?cacheBuster='+Math.random();
    var iFrame=document.getElementById('myPingTest');
    iFrame.onload=pingTime;
    iFrame.src=imgSrc;
    function pingTime() {
      var endTime=new Date();
      var pingResult = (endTime.getTime()-window.startTime);
      if(pingResult<hidden.hidden.value){
        document.getElementById('pingT').innerHTML = '<center>' + pingResult + '</center>';
        hidden.hidden.value=pingResult;
      }else{document.getElementById('pingT').innerHTML = '<center>' + hidden.hidden.value + '</center>';}
      } 
    } 
  }
</script>

<IFRAME style="display:none;" id=myPingTest></IFRAME>
<FORM NAME="hidden" STYLE="display:none"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="hidden" value="100000"></form>
<br>
<FORM method="get" NAME="ping" action="javascript:initPingTest(ping.url.value);"><font>Enter site adress(ie.www.yahoo.com)<br>http://</font>
  <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="url" size="18"><input type="submit" value="Ping"/></form>
  <br>
  <table cellspacing=5px>
    <tr><th>
      Url:
    </th><th>
      Ping Time (miliseconds)
    </th></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <label id=site><center> - </center></label>
    </td><td>
      <label id=pingT><center> - </center></lable>
    </td></tr>
  </table>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't believe Javascript 'really' offers this kind of functionality, you could create an xmlhttprequest object, and perhaps compare the difference from the time it sends with the time it connects.

The following code shows a possible way to achieve this:
Edit: should alert if the server is down now

```
var address = "http://www.google.com";

var t1 = Date.now();
var t2;

var max = 100000;
var failed = false;

var httpReq = (window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
if(httpReq == null) {
    console.log("Error: XMLHttpRequest failed to initiate.");
}
httpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {

    var failTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                               failed = true;
                               httpReq.abort();
                               }, max);

    if (httpReq.readyState == 4) {  //Completed loading
        if (!failed && (httpReq.status == 200 || httpReq.status == 0)) {

            clearTimeout(failTimer);

            t2 = Date.now();

            var timeTotal = (t2 - t1);
            if(timeTotal > max) {
                onFail();
            } else {
                onSuccess(timeTotal);
            }

        }
        else {  //Otherwise, there was a problem while loading
            console.log("Error " + httpReq.status + " has occurred.");
            onFail();
        }
    }
}
try {
    httpReq.open("GET", address, true);
    httpReq.send(null);

} catch(e) {
    console.log("Error retrieving data httpReq. Some browsers only accept cross-domain request with HTTP.");
    onFail();
}


function onSuccess(timeTotal) {

    alert("Time needed to connect: " + timeTotal);
}
function onFail() {
    alert("Well this isn't good");
}
```

An iframe may be a viable solution as well though.

Comment: its works fine when the webpage is online, but when it is not it doesnt load onFail() ..stil, +1 for the very nice tip!

Comment: Whoops. Ok, I added that functionality. Please tell me if you have any more problems.

Comment: It doesnt seem to do anything on IE and in google chrome it always says it always connects even if the site is non existant.. im starting to think this is achievable only with php or a similar server-side scripting language..

Comment: I'm not the best programmer :) though client-sided languages will always have this problem; it doesn't always work the same for everyone.

Comment: yes, i see that, unfortunately, almost nothing in programming is quite canonical.. as soon as i am done with javascript ill learn ajax or php. Im still a noob, but i see that the more languages you know the more freedom you have to make your own rules, and systems. to play with the possibilities is just amazing.. Thanks for your help and understanding!

Comment: Sure. BTW, AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript And XML) is Javascript; the code above is essentially AJAX.