# Detect if another website is online or not in javascript

Tags: angular

Hi I am using Angular and iframe. I would like to detect if the target website is online or not before load it into the iframe.  I am currently using the following code

```
try {
  await this._httpClient.get(url, { observe: 'response' }).toPromise();
} catch (error) {
  return error.status === 200;
}
```

However, it takes more than 20 seconds to check one website when the website it offline, but quite quick when the website is online. Is there faster way to detect if a target website is online or not? Thank you

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469249/how-to-check-if-site-is-online-with-javascript-plus-tips-on-how-to-make-the-res

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if site is online with JavaScript? Plus tips on how to make the rest of this function work better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469249/how-to-check-if-site-is-online-with-javascript-plus-tips-on-how-to-make-the-res)

Answer (score 1):

You can send request for other static small file like simple css file or image file of that site instead of site content.

Comment: Hi Romeo, thank you for your suggestion. However, the issue of my code is that when the website is offline, it takes more than 20 seconds to return a timeout, then it will move to check the next website. So not exactly sure how much loading a small static file will help. Actually when the website is online, my code detects much quicker than detecting an offline website.

Comment: If you think so, you can give timeout before sending request.